# Adding css class when component will mount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I add some class to the `body` element when a `Modal` is open

```
const Modal = ({ ... }) => {
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.classList.add('modal-open')
        return () => document.body.classList.remove('modal-open')
    }, [])
```

But I notice there is a quick and short delay when applying the `modal-open` class (especially when this class contains some styles like `margin-right: 17px`, `overflow-y: hidden` and `position: sticky !important`) So i see the `body` element moving Which is not a good user experience of course.

So i moved adding the class out of the `useEffect`

```
document.body.classList.add('modal-open')
useEffect(() => { ... }, [])
```

And it is working but this line of code `document.body.classList.add('modal-open')` is executed at every re-render and not just once as within `useEffect`

So is there a better approch ? maybe `componentWillMount` equivalent in hooks cause i'm not touching the state i'm just manipulating dom elements classes ?

Comment: try https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect instead

Comment: thanks @UjinT34 it did work ;) you can write an answer to be accepted if you want ... i also find this article very usefull https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) can be used instead of `useEffect` to apply changes earlier.

> The signature is identical to useEffect, but it fires synchronously
>   after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and
>   synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will
>   be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.